# Object's structure overriding defined methods?

Tags: c++, class

I have a class called `Object`:

```
class Object {
  public:
    Vector pos;
    float emittance;
    Vector diffuse;

    virtual float intersection(Ray&) {};
    virtual Vector getNormal(Vector&) {};
};
```

And another class which inherits it:

```
class Sphere: public Object {
  public:
    float radius;

    virtual float intersection(Ray &ray) {
      Vector distance;
      float b, c, d;

      distance = ray.origin - pos;
      b = distance.dot(ray.direction);
      c = distance.dot(distance) - radius*radius;
      d = b*b - c;

      cout << -b - sqrt(d);

      if (d > 0.0) {
        return -b - sqrt(d);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    virtual Vector getNormal(Vector position) {
      return (position - pos).norm();
    }
};
```

When I compiled the program, I was expecting it to start spitting out tons and tons of lines of text. But for some reason, that whole method (the `intersection()` method) is never actually called at all!

Why is my `intersection()` function from the `Sphere` class not overriding the default on found in the `Object` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not declare the function as `virtual` and make sure that the method signature matches. Change it to:

```
class Object{    
    virtual float intersection(Ray) {};
    virtual Vector getNormal(Vector) {};
}

class Sphere: public Object {
    ...
    virtual float intersection(Ray ray) {
...
```

Comment: Where would I put that? I tried this before in the `Object` class, but it didn't help.

Comment: Plus it's not got the same prototype.

Comment: Also he has a `const` declaration but a non-const prototype

Comment: @Blender - can you show us the code you're using to create the object and call it?

Comment: To create it? I use this: `Sphere sphere = Sphere();`.

Comment: But I am looping over a collection of different `Objects` (planes, spheres, etc.) using this function: `Vector Trace(Ray &ray, vector<Object*> objects, ...`. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the derived class takes a reference, and the Object class does not. Secondly, the Object declares them as non-const, and the Sphere defines them as const. These both mean that you're not actually overriding the same function.

Comment: g++ even provides a helpful warning that you're hiding the parent method.

Comment: I tried changing `intersection(Ray) {};` to `intersection(Ray&) {};` and it didn't seem to do anything. Also, if you look at the code I updated, I removed all the `const`s and added `virtual`s. Not sure what is wrong, though...

Comment: @Mark, when I compile, I get no warnings at all. Might be because I don't include any flags, but here's my compile command: `g++ engine.cpp -o engine`