# template class containing a stdvector of references to its own instances

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I'm relatively new to C++, and am trying for the first time to build a complex template structure.

How can I declare, as member of a template class Foo, a std::vector of Foo* elements, but that could be of various types?

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Foo {
    T mValue;
    std::vector< Foo<T>* > mFooParameters;  // <---- I would like this vector to contain
                                            //       any sort of Foo<T>* elements,
                                            //       Foo<int>*, Foo<double>*, etc.
};
```

Is it straightforward, possible but complicated, or impossible?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274136/objects-of-different-classes-in-a-single-vector, but I fail to understand how the text of your question relates to its title.

Comment: Thank you jogojapan. It's probably because I got lost in the template thingy. I'm looking into your link!

Comment: So, is it a duplicate? (If not, what is the difference?)

Comment: It is not completely a duplicate in that I thought there was a difficulty intrinsic to my using templates. Polymorphism is the answer though, see my comment to @h3nr1x 's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your vector types are all related, use polymorphism as explained in the link provided by @jogojapan, if the types are not related at all, use a vector of `void*` to hold pointers to your data (kind of messy though)

Comment: I think I'll use polymorphism to top all possible `Foo<T>` with a unique, more general definition. Thank you!