# Indexing operator of an object owned by unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, subscript-operator

I am working on a C++ project. I need to put different classes into `std::vector`. I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274136/objects-of-different-classes-in-a-single-vector) that this indeed is possible by creating classes with a common type and then putting pointers in the vector. In this case, I could cast the pointers to the type I need. That much is clear to me.

It is also mentioned that in principle it is possible to use not just pointers but smart pointers, i.e, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TMyClass>>`. This is where my problem begins. `TMyClass` has the indexing operator (`operator[]`).

Let's say I have `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TMyClass>> A`. I try to access an element of the `TMyClass` object like `A[0][0]` or `A[0].get()[0]` or `(A[0])[0]`, but when I compile I get an error:

`[bcc64 Error] type 'value_type' (aka 'std::unique_ptr<.....>') does not provide a subscript operator`

How can I tell the compiler that the second index is related to the `TMyClass` object and not to `unique_ptr`? I would highly appreciate if somebody would explain to me how to access elements in this case.

Comment: Did you try `(*A[0])[0]`? The unique pointer is like a pointer - you have to use the dereferencing operator `*` to access its contents.

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: @Ron: thanks for your reply. Do you mean overloading the operator of std::unique_ptr? But then it will probably not work with the array form of unique_ptr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extract pointer first

```
A[0]  //type: std::unique_ptr<TMyClass>&
```

Then extract object from that pointer (pointee)

```
*A[0] //type: TMyClass&
```

And then you can use your overloaded operators on this object

```
(*A[0])[0]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! This seems to work. With `(*A[0])[0]` I get basically the access to the element. And I need to cast it to another type is `(TMyClass2*)(&(*A[0])[0])` a proper way to do this or can it be done in an easier way?

Comment: @Alexander Don't use C-style casts, this is asking for trouble. What is the type of `(*A[0])[0]`? How does it convert to `TMyClass2`?

Comment: @Alexander At the very least, I suggest creating a named variable (probably a reference) before using `(*A[0])[0]` or it will quickly become a syntax hell. Something like this: `auto& myObject = (*A[0])[0];`

Comment: `(*A[0])[0]` has type of `TMyClass`. Basically `struct TMyClass2 : public TMyClass {}`. `TMyClass2` cointains more variables.

Comment: @Alexander Show the definitions of `TMyClass` and `TMyClass2` in your question. Does the base class have virtual functions that you implement in `TMyClass2`? If so, you don't need to cast, just call them.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Both `TMyClass` and `TMyClass2` have no functions just variables.

Comment: @Alexander So your operator is like `TMyClass& TMyClass::operator[](size_t)`? If you really need to cast, use `dynamic_cast<TMyClass2*>(&((*A[0])[0]));`, but downcasting classes to derived ones is a bad smell. It suggests that something is wrong with your design.

Comment: @Alexander I think this answer should be accepted since it solves the problem you asked about. The casting problem is different problem. Ask a new question for that if you can't find an answer for it here on SO already.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I am sorry I made a mistake in my previous comments. `TMyClass` has an array of type `TMyClass2[]` and the `TMyClass2 operator[](size_t)`. `TMyClass2` has only variables with no functions. `(*A[0])[0]` has type of `TMyClass2` and this type I need to convert to another class `TMyClass3: public TMyClass2`.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers must be dereferenced. So, I would guess `(*A[0])[0]` <strike>or `A[0]->[0]`</strike>. Not nice looking, but that's pointers for you

Comment: Did you ever try `A[0]->[0]`? If you want to go this way, I would suggest `A[0]->operator[](0)` instead. ;-) (But `(*A[0])[0]` looks somehow more compact and convenient.)

Comment: @Yaroslav Fyodorov Thanks for your comments! With `(*A[0])[0]` I get basically the access to the element. And I need to cast it to another type is `(TMyClass2*)(&(*A[0])[0])` a proper way to do this or can it be done in an easier way?

Comment: Perhaps I need to refresh my cpp. It somehow got contaminated by Perl why I wasn't using either of them. I knew [0]->[0] doesn't look c++ enough

Comment: @Alexander I am getting confused here. Now there is TMyClass2 out of the blue. Who inherits from whom? And which vector holds pointers to base class?
Based on your initial question I would think you want to do

`A[0]` to access the shared_ptr obj
`A[0].get()` to get the underlining pointer, 
and `(TMyClass2*)A[0].get()` to cast it. That is based on the assumption that TMyClass2 inherits from TMyClass.
But then I am not sure what indexing operator on TMyClass got to do with that.

Comment: @Alexander If what you wrote in the comments to your question, that is `TMyClass` has an array of type `TMyClass2[]` and the `TMyClass2 operator[](size_t)` is correct, then you cannot cast object returned by `(*A[0])[0]` because it's not a pointer and not a reference. In any case, array of type `TMyClass2[]` cannot possibly hold objects of class `TMyClass3: TMyClass2`